# Atom Editor CSS lint setting

Tags: css, atom-editor, lint

I am trying to get this working but it does not seem very strict.

When I miss out a semi-colon it does not even let me know. Can this be tweaked?

I ideally I would like to enforce some rule order too.

https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/outside-in-ordering-css-properties-by-importance--cms-21685

Comment: Probably best asking this on the atom forum? https://discuss.atom.io/

Answer (score 1):

Install the [`linter`](https://atom.io/packages/linter), [`linter-ui-default`](https://atom.io/packages/linter-ui-default), and [`linter-csslint`](https://atom.io/packages/linter-csslint) packages. You can install them all with this command in the terminal:

```
$ apm install linter linter-ui-default linter-csslint
```